# Reusing raid1 disks by wiping them (Windows)

Tags: hard-drive, raid-1

I had a raid 1 desktop system with 2 1tb drives. The motherboard died.

I bought a motherboard without Raid capability (ASUS B250-Plus)

When I put the old drives in the new system, it seems the motherboard still raids the drive but it doesn't allow me to CTRL+1 to get to the raid controller.

I've tried everything that DISKPART will let me do to "unraid" the disks but they just keep pairing back up.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your manual to make sure whenever it has one or doesn't. If it doesn't (assuming you used hardware raid before) you will likely have to format the drives to make them usable (this wipes ALL data).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have checked the manual of the new motherboard - it does not have raid. 
Formatting the drives doesn't remove the raid, as soon as you put them back in the machine together they pair back up and the intel software copies all data from the 'master' raided drive and windows sees the drives as one.

Comment: What Intel software? Did you check the settings of that software?

Comment: The intel software is IAStorUI (Intel Rapid Storage Technology 15.2.7.1042). I'm not sure where it came from. I possibly loaded it when I built the computer. It runs in system tray and reports problems with disk storage. It is unable to see (or does not show) the raided disks but shows any other disks attached to the motherboard.

Comment: I've been through every bit of the interface but there is nothing available to manage the raid array, The help has a section on managing raid arrays and indicates that running the program as admin will allow you to manage raid arrays but when I run the program as admin it still doesn't see the raided disks or give any management options via the interface.

Comment: Did you try to remove it from your system?

Comment: Remove what? The software, the raid array or one of the disks? The disks are raided (or linked in some way) so that if you load one of the disks via usb and one internally it doesn't show the USB disk on my system (Win explorer, m'soft management console, diskpart etc). If you detach the disk internally then windows sees the USB version. If you plug both internally then only one drive is found by windows. If you boot with a win 10 installation disk then diskpart sees both disks but if you run diskpart from recovery mode or from a command prompt it only sees one disk using list disk.

Comment: The Intel software at that is what seems to keep them as a raid. Did you format both disks while having them individually attached in order to see whenever that will delete the raid information on those disks so the Intel software doesn't interfere? That could be another approach.

Comment: I'll give that a go, hopefully at the weekend, and let you know.

Comment: Just to make this also clear: By formatting the disks you will loose any data that's still on those disks.

Comment: Yep, thanks - always worth mentioning! I'm juggling disks at the moment to make sure I have safe copies of all of my data as I try to set a backup system .

Comment: No success! I formatted each drive without the other plugged in and it didn't remove the raid. I also proved it's not the Intel Software that is keeping them as raid because I did everything in Linux. I formatted the first drive as ext4 and the 2nd as NTFS. I copied the data by onto each disk. I then put both drives in, booted to Ubuntu and the NTFS disk got wiped. Linux couldn't read it and it said the partition was formatted as ext but no volume or data existed and Linux showed a raided drive (as well a the 2 physical drives). The ext4 drive kept it's data.

Comment: Eventually I managed to solve the problem. Unfortunately, I'd given up trying to unraid and can't remember what I did. It certainly, involved formatting at ext4 and formatting in both linux and windows. The Intel Rapid Storage Technology program in sys tray shows everything happy. I really didn't think I'd done anything different but there we are....